# Android 4.4.2 Animation Fade in and Fade out

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have an application using fade in and fade out animations. It works properly on a device which is android 4.2.2. However the same application does not show the animation on device 4.4.2. These are my xml files

res/anim/fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

res/anim/fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.1" />
```

And this is the place where i call fade out animation.

```
animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);    
aim.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
```

I strongly wonder why it is ok for version 4.2.2 but not working on 4.4.2. Can you help me?

Regards

Comment: in which device you tested that?

Comment: for 4.2.2 it was google galaxy nexus.  for 4.4.2 it was nexus 5 and my exper t7q brand tablet. first two are emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it the defaut fade out and fade in

```
animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);    
aim.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
```

Comment: This is not the answer of my question. I wonder why it does not work on 4.4.2 but it works on 4.2.2. By the way, your solution also not working on 4.4.2